# Flask sessions don't persist in Debian/UWSGI server

Tags: python, flask, debian, uwsgi

This is my first project trying to run a Flask app using UWSGI in my Debian server, and I'm really not able to decipher why my sessions don't keep the variables when I'm changing URLs.

My code is similar to this:

```
...

app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "myserver.com"

...

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        session['username'] = username
        return render_template('query.html')

@app.route('/do_query/<query>')
def do_query(query):    
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    ...

app.secret_key = 'idjaon21ioj'
```

As you can see, I tried to include the `SERVER_NAME` variable and to use a custom string in `app.secret_key` for testing purposes, since these two answers were given in similar questions regarding the same problem. But I still could make the `do_query()` function to find the `username` variable in the session object.

What can my mistake be?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending a POST to `login` that contains a field named `username`?

Comment: definitely check @dirn's comment (he's pretty much always spot-on); that said, you might also want to relegate user access to a proper library like [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which does a lot of the work for you (and properly- authentication and user access control is a very tricky problem).

Comment: Check if flask is properly reading and writing cookies.

Comment: @dirn yes I am. I just put a `print(session)` command before `return render_template('query.html')` and got this in my log file: `<SecureCookieSession {'username': 'rodrigoburg'}>`. I can't really figure how to debug deeper...

Comment: @GG_Python I definitely want to change to flask-login as soon as possible, but right now I just want a functioning example as a showcase to my boss.